# ngTagsInput - How to block removing tags via 'Backspace'

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

The [ngTagsInput](https://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/) library does not have an option to disable removing tags via the 'Backspace' key.

Adding a normal keydown event will not suffice, because you need to intercept the existing event not add a new one, so any attempt to `event.preventDefault()` will not work.

Any ideas how to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with is to short circuit the `on-tag-removing` function like so:

```
        # Weird hack to prevent backspace deleting of tags
        # "selected" is the red treatment you get (early warning)
        # to indicate that the next backspace will delete the tag.
        # TODO: It'd be nice to have this NOT throw:
        # 'Possibly unhandled rejection: undefined'
        # But...could easily live with this in the console.
        if document.querySelector('.tag-item.selected')
          return false
```

**NOTE** Do yourself a favor and check your version of ngTagsInput matches the current version of the online docs as the `on-tag-removing` function has changed to handle async/promises differently.  This example works using the current newest version.

**NOTE** If you want other instances of the ngTagsInput to allow the deleting, you might have to more accurately scope the querySelector!